# How can I automatically transfer data between R-Base database version 4 and SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, import

I'm looking to set up a recurring data import from a very old, R-Base 4 database, into SQL Server 2008. I know close to nothing about R-Base databases - is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to have to roll your own.  You can use SQL Server Integration Services to pull data through the RBase ODBC connector.  SSIS can manage the change detection stuff for you, but when I say that, I don't want you to get the impression it's going to be easy.

The good news is that SSIS is a pretty mainstream technology at this point, so you could hire a consultant to build this kind of thing for you.

Comment: I've come to pretty much the same conclusion. Drats.